Orchid budding a 2nd plant - can I detach and repot?
My orchid is budding a keiki off the main leaves at the base of the plant. I've looked online and all I've seen are 2nd plants growing higher up from the flower stems.  Is it safe to take this little guy off and repot?

Can you wait until it's a teen and not a newborn? Or maybe leave it to twin?
